# Moment.js get last 28 days

Tags: momentjs

I am using React-Native.
Is there any way in Moment.js to get the last 28 days from now? I saw a plugin `moment-range` but I do not want to install it.

Basically what I need is an array of the last 28 days.

Example:

```
const now = moment()
const lastMonth = moment.subtract(28, 'days')
const lastMonthArr = [1,2....28]
```

Comment: Can't you calculate with timestamps? I find that to be the easiest way to do such things in the tools I'm working with. `date = timestamp - (28 * 24 * 60 * 60)` is pretty easy to get around.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
let now = moment();
let pastDates = [];
for( let i=1;i<=28;i++) { 
 now = now.subtract(1, 'day')
  console.log(now.format('MMM Do YY'))
  pastDates.push(now)
}
```